# Start function after content generated

Tags: javascript, jquery

`loadJSON(url, callback)` - function with callback to load JSON with data.
I get data from callback and generate page like this (function is onclick):

```
    function getForm(some, param) {
     loadJSON('tables.json', function (response) {
         var list = JSON.parse(response);
         result += some - clever - code;
         document.getElementById('ol').innerHTML = result;
         document.getElementById('hidediv').className = '';
     });
 }
```

My question is how to start other function, after form is generated? 
And this function must be active till form change again (it's radio buttons listener). I don't want add `onclick=` to any element of form.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to handle 'onclick' event for every radio button from loaded elements?

Comment: Only to some radio groups. After form created, I choose groups with '^word^' in their names and then start this function - http://www.pastebin.ca/2630111

Answer (score 0):

You can add `click` handler for all radio buttons in loaded part:

```
 $("input:radio").click(function()
 {
      alert("click handled!");
 });
```

Comment: And when I need to put this? How I can sure that form is loaded?